# answer = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase(); dont know whats wrong

Tags: java

In line 23 i have a misstake and i cant figure out what it is please help, i tried nearly everything (keep in mind im learning java) I would aprecciate every help
Also it should look like this when its done if someone would help it would be perfect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Rollercoaster
 */
public class Rollercoaster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner age=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How old are ya?");
        int a = age.nextInt();

        if (a >= 14) {

            System.out.println("Come in!");

        } else if (a >= 6) {        

            String answer;
            boolean YesNo;
            
            System.out.println("Are your Perants with you?");
            while (true) {
              Scanner in;
            answer = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
              if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                YesNo = true;
                System.out.println("Come in!");
                break;
              } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
                YesNo = false;
                System.out.println("Go Home Kid!");
                break;
              } else {
                 System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't get that, come again!");
              }
        }

        
            
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWJe8.png)

Comment: First problem is that you are trying to have many Scanners which will handle same opened resource `System.in`. Just don't do it. Have one scanner and name it properly (so instead of `age` name it `scanner` or `input` or something which will be more general than `age` since it is now what it is, nor represents). Then why are you trying to use `nextLine().trim()`? If you want to get single token use `next()`. You also don't need to convert entire string to lowercase to compare it with other string, use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

Comment: Which error you got?  NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize the Scanner `in` in line 22. Therefore, the compiler will start complaining in line 23, that you are trying to use a not initialized variable.

You could initialize the object: `= new Scanner(System.in)`, but I think reusing the Scanner `age` would also work and would probably also look cleaner (just rename it to something like `scanner` maybe?).

PS: For the next question: If there is an error, always also give us the error message.

Comment: Local variables don't have initial values, `in` will not hold `null` which could cause NPE. Instead problem will appear earlier, at compilation time because compiler will not allow such code to compile with uninitialized variable. Anyway second advice is correct, OP should be using one Scanner in that code, not many scanners just to read many values.

Comment: What do you mean by "Local variables don't have initial values"? Never heard of that. Are there other non-primitive variables that do have initial values? Could you perhaps give me an example? [Asking out of curiosity]

Comment: If we don't *explicitly* assign value to *local variable* but will try to use it such code will not compile so also can't run. Example: https://ideone.com/Hh1Njg. Note that there is a deference between local variables (which are *declared* inside methods/constructors/initialization blocks) and class *fields* (defined at top level of class). When field is not explicitly initialized, compiler will generate code assigning it default value like 0, false, null. But that will not happen to *local* variables.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Reason: `Scanner in` is not initialized.

Possible solution I suggest, Replace the line:

```java
 Scanner in;
```

with:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rollercoaster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner age=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How old are ya?");
        int a = age.nextInt();

        if (a >= 14) {
            System.out.println("Come in!");
        } else{
            String answer;
            boolean YesNo;

            System.out.println("Are your Parents with you?");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // initialize like this

            while (true) {
                answer = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                    YesNo = true;
                    System.out.println("Come in!");
                    break;
                } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
                    YesNo = false;
                    System.out.println("Go Home Kid!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't get that, come again!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```